# NP hardness - Why is one harder than the other?

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, np

As far as my understanding goes, to show that a problem A is NP-hard, we use another NP-complete problem B. We reduce (in polynomial time) from B to A, i.e. use A to solve B. This shows that A is harder than or equal to B, which proves that it is NP-hard.

However, I don't understand why A is harder than B? I feel like I'm missing a part after the reduction step.

Apologies if my understanding is wrong, or if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: As you said yourself, A is not necessarily harder than B -- it's just *at least as hard* as B.  For this to be false, A would have to be *easier* than B -- but that can't possibly be, since the reduction describes a way to encode *any* B instance as an A instance -- meaning that literally every B-instance you can think of can be written as an A-instance.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense :) Feel free to add it as an answer if you wish, though this question has been marked as duplicate now.